# Replace elements of a list with Prolog

Tags: prolog

how to replace any of the element in the list with prolog?

example:

```
replace(2,[1,2,3,2,1],5,X)
```

should have both the solutions:

- `X = [1,5,3,2,1]`
- `X = [1,2,3,5,1]`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a complete code solution rather than asking for help on any specific attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by iterating over the input list:

```
%replace(_, [], _, []).
replace(Element, [Element|Tail], NElement, [NElement|Tail]).
replace(Element, [CurElement|Tail], NElement, [CurElement|NTail]):-
  replace(Element, Tail, NElement, NTail).
```

Sample input:

```
?- replace(2,[1,2,3,2,1],5,X).
X = [1, 5, 3, 2, 1] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1] ;
```

If you uncomment the first clause it would also output the solution where the output list remains unchanged.

The first clause (commented) is a base case for iterating over a list. It states that the replaced list of an empty list is the empty itself.

The second clause states that if the head of the list unifies with the Element then the replace list would contain the replaced element and the rest of the list (Tail).

The third clause is the recursive step, it takes the first element and calls recursively with the tail of the list, and the output is the element taken concatenated with the result of the recursive call.

Comment: @fanrenwu: It's the Prolog comment marker. That clause is commented out; if you remove the % then that clause would be part of the procedure so it would add a base case for the recursion.